# Using Java To run a shell script to copy a file to docker returns an error

Tags: java, bash, shell, docker

I'm trying to use Java to execute a shell script that triggers a docker copy command. Everything I have tried has returned code 127 (command not found).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Starting shell script");
    String script = "SendToDocker.sh";
    String scriptPath = "/path/";
    try {
        Process awk = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", scriptPath + script).start();
        awk.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(        
                awk.getInputStream()));                                          
            String s;                                                                
            while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {                                
              System.out.println("Script output: " + s);
              System.out.println("output code: "+awk.exitValue());
            }      
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Finished");
}
```

SendToDocker.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
docker cp /path/asdf.csv 2d55a8445409:/
```

The script works perfectly fine if I run it in my terminal. Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Docker requires root privilege, maybe you need to run your java program with root privilege.

Comment: 'which docker' put full path of docker binary in your .sh script.

Comment: I can run docker on my user without using sudo, but I'm not sure how to use sudo inside a Java program.  Also I'm running this on OSX and am having trouble locating the physical docker files. docker cp does copy to the containerID i provided when I run  the sh file from terminal.

Comment: 1. As debugging point, you can try to ls files in `/path/` inside of java program, to see if there is script in the right place.    
2. To see where is problem is, I also would suggest try run something like
`Process awk = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "docker cp /path/asdf.csv 2d55a8445409:/").start();` and see what happen. Hope this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

*) Go to the directory where the Dockerfile is

*) docker build -t your_app_name .

*) docker run -it your_app_name

Answer (score 0):

Try some docker api for java jar?
Here is a example:

https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/tree/master/src/test/java/com/github/dockerjava/core/command

Comment: If you just want to fix this issue.My answer may be a little heavy.

Comment: But if you want to call more docker command in java, this may help.